# poolmon: Which driver uses "Thre"?

Tags: drivers, memory-leak, poolmon

One step further: On my machine, the pool tagged "Thre" grows about 1MB/day. Searching for "Thre" with `findstr` returns about every `*.sys` file on my harddisk. Any ideas how I could reduce the number of possible culprits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try downloading the Debugging Tools for Windows.  It includes a pooltag.txt that includes the common tags and what they represent.  In your case:

Thre - nt!ps        - Thread objects

Also, the newer versions of poolmon (e.g. http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2105564e-1a9a-4bf4-8d74-ec5b52da3d00&displaylang=en) apparently have a "/c" parameter that will show this information within poolmon itself (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms792885.aspx#a0735340-c309-44d2-9e42-0d018029ad54)